# Simplifying product of matrix exponential?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Is there a known generalization for n-term matrix exponential multiplication?

I am aware that the Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula could be used, e.g.:

```
expm(A) * expm(B) = expm(A + B + [A,B]/2 + ...)
```

But is there any (simple) formulation for n terms, e.g. like this?

```
expm(A_1) * ... * expm(A_n) = expm(A_1 + ... + A_n + ???)
```

Additionally, I wonder if it would be possible to find a simpler formula, if it is known that:

```
A_i = B + C_i
```

so that:

```
expm(B + C_1) * ... * expm(B + C_n)
```

Note that `B` and `C_i` are not commuting and not nilpotent, so I do not see much free lunch over there, but `C_i` is very sparse and actually it might be possible to find a direct formula for `expm(C_i)`.

Also, I am specifically interested in a faster computation of:

```
expm(B + C_1) * ... * expm(B + C_n)
```

and I thought it would be cheaper to trade of some expm() with some matrix multiplication...

p.s. they are all `n x n` invertible square matrix.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_exponential#Product_of_exponentials

Comment: thanks for the link but I do not find an immediate application to my problem.. the formula you linked is hardly any easier to compute than the direct problem